# How to get RelativePanel's Canvas.Top value in C# code?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have code as below. Which puts a RelativePanel inside of a Canvas. And I apply animation onto the panel, which will move it down 230 pixels, i.e. to change its `Canvas.Top="0"` to `Canvas.Top="230"`

In the C# code, I need to detect whether the animation works. So I need to get the Canvas.Top of the RelativePanel.
But how?
Thanks!

```
<Canvas x:Name="toolbarCanvas" Margin="0,0,0,-50" Height="140" Width="1000" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True">
    <RelativePanel x:Name="toolbarPanel" Margin="0,0,0,0" Canvas.Top="230">
        <Image x:Name="toolbarBackground" Source="Assets/MainPage/toolbar/toolbar-background.png" Height="140" Width="1000" Stretch="Uniform" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Canvas.Top is an attached property you can simply use:

```cs
var top = Canvas.GetTop(toolbarPanel);
```